# aiohttp Runtime Error: Cannot guess the encoding of a not yet read body

Tags: python, json, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Working on an asynchronous API wrapper for `https://wanderbox.org/api`. I'm using the aiohttp to handle most of the asynchronous networking. For one POST method, I keep getting the following error

```
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/wander/wander/tests/test_client.py", line 114, in coro
    x = await Wandbox.compile_nd(
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/wander/wander/client.py", line 198, in compile_nd
    return await cls._post(url=cls.url.format("compile.ndjson"), data=json.dumps(params), headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/wander/wander/client.py", line 74, in _post
    encoding = response.get_encoding()
  File "/Users/dominictarro/Documents/wander/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1063, in get_encoding
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot guess the encoding of a not yet read body
```

It only occurs for this one API endpoint, `https://wanderbox.org/api/compile.ndjson`. Every other test case is passing. The API for this case is returning an NDJSON which may be causing issues. but it doesn't even get to that error because of the `response.get_encoding()`.

Here are my `_post` and `compile_nd` functions.

```
@classmethod
async def _post(cls, url, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    TODO describe

    :param url:
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    async with cls.session.post(*args, url=url, ssl=False, **kwargs) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        return await response.json(content_type=response.content_type, encoding=response.get_encoding())

@classmethod
    async def compile_nd(
            cls,
            code: str,
            compiler: str,
            codes: typing.List[dict] = (),
            compiler_option_raw: typing.Any = '',
            options: str = '',
            runtime_option_raw: typing.Any = '',
            stdin: str = '',
            **kwargs
    ):
        """
        Sends code to Wandbox to be compiled with the given parameters and returns performance/completion dictionaries.

        :param code:                Code to compile and execute
        :param compiler:            Compiler name as described by Wandbox
        :param codes:               List of supplementary code objects {'code': abcd..., 'file': 'demo.py'}
        :param compiler_option_raw: ...
        :param options:             Compiler options (as would be typed in terminal)
        :param runtime_option_raw:  ...
        :param stdin:               Data to feed into input calls from running program
        :param kwargs:              Keyword arguments to modify aiohttp ClientSession().post() method
        :return:                    
        """
        params = {
            'code': code,
            'codes': codes,
            'compiler': compiler,
            'compiler-option-raw': compiler_option_raw,
            'options': options,
            'runtime-option-raw': runtime_option_raw,
            'stdin': stdin
        }
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-ndjson', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        return await cls._post(url=cls.url.format("compile.ndjson"), data=json.dumps(params), headers=headers, **kwargs)
```

Here is the test case raising the error.

```
def test_compile_nd_simple(self):

    async def coro():
        await Wandbox.connect()

        code = "import os\nprint(os.name)\nprint('done')"
        x = await Wandbox.compile_nd(
            code=code,
            compiler='cpython-3.8.0',
            compiler_option_raw=False,
            runtime_option_raw=True
        )
        keys = ('program_message', 'program_output', 'status')
        self.assertTrue(sorted(x.keys()) == sorted(keys), msg=f"{x}\n-----\n{keys}")

        await Wandbox.close()

    asyncio.run(coro())
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Firstly, I think there's an issue with the `response.get_encoding()` function that is outside of my control. However, I can just use `response.charset` (this assumes the server provides it, but for my purposes it does).

Secondly, the loading issue is solved by importing the `ndjson` library and using its `Decoder().decode` function if `content_type == "application/x-ndjson"`. If not, just use the standard `json` decoder `JSONDecoder().decode` function.

My code now looks like this.

```
import json
import ndjson

@classmethod
async def _post(cls, url, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    TODO describe

    :param url:
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    async with cls.session.post(*args, url=url, ssl=False, **kwargs) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        return await cls._parse_response(response)

@classmethod
async def _parse_response(cls, response: aiohttp.ClientResponse) -> typing.Any:
    """
    Takes an aiohttp.ClientResponse object and converts content to Python primitives via json or ndjson

    :param response:
    :return:
    """
    decoder = ndjson.Decoder if (response.content_type == 'application/x-ndjson') else json.JSONDecoder
    return await response.json(content_type=response.content_type, loads=decoder().decode, encoding=response.charset)
```